# Choosing Erlang webserver

Tags: erlang, webserver, yaws, cowboy, webmachine

Yep, subjective question. But here are a lot of such questions that got good answers. So now I have to try to develop some REST API with Erlang, as I got from google I have to install some webserver, such as Cowboy, Webmachine, Yaws, Mociweb. But all information I can find is too old and seems to be non-actual. So what server still keeps on developing and how can I choose one for me? Am I wrong at all at this way?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you want. Mochiweb is a minimalistic library for http-servers, that would fit niceley to a newly built REST-API. Together with a SQL/persistence-library such as epgsql, you have a powerful combo.

Comment: This kind of question might fit better on the [Erlang mailing list](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/), but you have to be more specific about your needs (you want the library with the best documentation? the one that's easiest for a newcomer? the one with the lowest response latency? the one that updates the most frequently?)

Comment: Thanks @NathanielWaisbrot. As a greatest purpose I have to build REST API service with about 450k request per day retreiving data from a Sybase ASE table with ~2 millions records. Of course I wanna get best performance and application avaliability

Comment: Cowboy is probably the most actively-developed of the ones you mention (at least as far as I am aware), and has excellent support for REST interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

You can't go wrong with Cowboy. It is actively being developed, with a 2.0 pre-release just made available. The documentation is excellent, and handles REST very well.

See: http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/1.0/guide/rest_handlers/ for the Cowboy REST support.